# Not full-rank jacobian and implicit function theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, implicit-function-theorem

$F:R^3 \to R^3 $ and $F \in C^1$
and let $a$ be a point where $F(a)=0$ and

$ DF|a = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial f_1/\partial x & \partial f_1/\partial y & \partial f_1/\partial z \\
\partial f_2/\partial x & \partial f_2/\partial y & \partial f_2/\partial z \\
\partial f_3/\partial x & \partial f_3/\partial y & \partial f_3/\partial z \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

where rank($DF|a)=2 \\$
let us assume that the determinant of $2\times2$ of the top right corner is non zero by applying the implicit function theorem there is a function $\varphi$ defined in D  and $a\in D$ where

$f_1(x,\varphi(x))=0$ and $f_2(x,\varphi(x))=0$

I try to prove that there is $D2 \subseteq D$ where
$f_3(x,\varphi(x))=0$

**my intuition** is that $F$ locally in point $a$ is similar to linear function to $DF|a$ and because the rank is 2 and $F(0)=0$ it is true that

$f_3=\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2$ at the point a

My intuition tells me it should be true for $D2.$

Comment: This is somewhat confusing to read. $\varphi$ is defined on an interval in $\Bbb R^1$, so we do not have $a\in D$. Moreover, assuming that the rank of $DF(a)$ is $2$ does not allow you to reason further; only if you know the rank of $DF$ is *constant* and equal to $2$ in a neighborhood of $a$ can you proceed. There is a generalization of the Implicit Function Theorem, called the Rank Theorem, that you can apply in that case. Try $F(x,y,z)=(y,z,x^2)$ at the origin, for example, to test out your reasoning.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need the rank theorem